# Does this dictionary confuse "start at" with "startled at"?

Tags: dictionary

[image]

我觉得是词典搞错了， 应该是 startle 才有”吃惊“的意思吧？

Comment: This should, perhaps, be migrated to English SE?

Comment: @user3306356 English section? Who can read the Chinese translation?

Comment: While nobody can read chinese there, you can formulate your question like so:

I found a chinese-english dictionary that lists one meaning of "start t at ..." to be "startled because of ...", is this an actual meaning, or is this simply a mistake?

Comment: Since you are certain 因...吃惊 means "startled at" in english, this is, in its core, an English question, isn't it? You are not asking about "whether 因...吃惊 means startled at", which would be a Chinese question.

Comment: But anyways, I'm pretty sure the dictionary is wrong.

Comment: @Zuoanqh: "While nobody can read chinese there ..." Well, I wouldn't make that assumption. You never know.

Comment: @马化腾: Yes, I think you're right. It should be "startled at". Perhaps a typo? Mistake of a proof reader? Neverthess, a mistake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Chinese language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be missing is that one of the meanings of the English word "start" is roughly synonymous with "startle" (in both its transitive and intransitive forms). From the Merriam-Webster dictionary:

```
Definition of start
intransitive verb
1 a : to move suddenly and violently, spring: *started* angrily to his feet
b : to react with a sudden brief involuntary movement: *started* when a shot rang out
[...]

transitive verb
1 : to cause to leave a place of concealment, flush: *start* a rabbit
```

Accordingly there does not seem to be any mistake in this dictionary, nor is this really a question about the Chinese language.

Comment: wait, why i never heard "start at" being used this way then? is this in-use?

Comment: @Zuoanqh I have never heard "start at" used this way in speech either, but have seen it in writing. Sometimes in fiction, it is said that a character "awoke with a start". (Try Googling that.)